# how to sync cookies in gwt client application and google app engine server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I develop gwt client application for web and i used google app engine for server 
I write the server in java
I send the requests to server with RequestBuilder 
how I can sync the cookies between server and client.
every request client send to server the server create new session 
I want to avoid it
in server I write code like this in every request

```
private void addCookies(){
    String jsessionId = request.getParameter("JSESSIONID");
    if (jsessionId != null && !jsessionId.isEmpty()) {
        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionId);
        response.addCookie(userCookie);
    } else {
        String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId);
        response.addCookie(userCookie);
    }
}
```

So for the first request I created cookie with sessionId and I return the session id to client in response

In client I write code like this

```
public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    Cookies.setCookie(JSESSIONID,  sessionId);
}
```

I get the sessionId from server and add to cookie

When i send request with RequestBuilder is see like this

```
public void sendRequest(final BaseRequest baseReuest){
    long currentTime = getApplicationServices().getTimeManager().getCurrentDate().getTime();
    if(isSessionIdle()){
        getBaseClientFactory().restart(true);
        return;
    }
    if(baseReuest.getOptionsRequest().isShowLoader()){
        showLoader(true);
        loaderRequestsCounter++;
    }
    try {
        String url = baseUrl + baseReuest.getMethodName();
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
        requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        baseReuest.addParam(JSESSIONID, getSessionId());
        requestBuilder.sendRequest(baseReuest.getParamsAsString(), new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                requestFinish(baseReuest);
                int status = response.getStatusCode();
                if(status == 200){
                    String json = response.getText();
                    BaseRequestResponse baseRequestResponse = baseReuest.buildResponse(json);
                    if(!baseRequestResponse.isSuccess()){
                        showFailureMessage(baseRequestResponse.getFailureResponse());
                    }
                    baseReuest.notifyResponse(baseRequestResponse);
                }
                else{
                    onErrorResponse();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                onErrorResponse();
            }
            private void onErrorResponse(){
                requestFinish(baseReuest);
                String message = getLabels().getLabel(IGeneralInfoLabels.THERE_IS_PROBLEM_ACCESSING_THE_SERVER);
                if(!isOnline()){
                    message = getApplicationServices().getGeneralManager().getLocalLabel().connectionNotAvailable();
                }
                FailureResponse failureResponse = new FailureResponse(message);
                showFailureMessage(failureResponse);
                baseReuest.notifyFailureResponse(failureResponse);
            }
            private void showFailureMessage(FailureResponse failureResponse){
                if(baseReuest.getOptionsRequest().isShowMessage()){
                    BaseRequestManager.this.showFailureMessage(failureResponse);
                }
            }
        });
        lastRequestSentTime = currentTime;
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        showLoader(false);
        requestFinish(baseReuest);
    }
}
```

for example for first request the sessionId is jk7br57mo1e5 so I add the sessionId to cookie in client 
but in every request the server created new sessionId why?
thank you